# how to insert a $_SESSION username into a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

i have a script where i can make and add news_items into a mysql database, but i want to insert the autor name... before you can make an item you have to login and the name is stored into a session... but how can i use that??

here is a bit of code:
the $rn was a test... but it wont work :(

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
include_once 'dbcon.php';

if(isset($_POST['save_mul']))
{       
    $total = $_POST['total'];

    for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++)
    {
        $fn = $_POST["fname$i"];
        $ln = $_POST["lname$i"];   
        $rn = $_POST [$_SESSION]'user'];
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO nieuws_bericht (title,berichten,aangemaakt) VALUES('".$fn."','".$ln."','".$rn."' ");
        $sql = $MySQLiconn->query($sql);        
    }

    if($sql)
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('<?php echo $total." bericht(en) zijn aangemaakt !!!"; ?>');
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while inserting , TRY AGAIN');
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you have some weird code in that `$rn` line. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Check my answer Mr @Reduan

Comment: @Reduankurtaj has your question been answered?

Comment: it still not working... i'm keep trying!!!!

Comment: @Reduankurtaj Does my answer not work? If so what errors are being thrown?

Comment: @JamieSterling i get this error... `        <script>
        alert('error while inserting , TRY AGAIN');
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>`

Comment: @ReduanKurtaj Which option were you using? I have a die call aswell to tell what is going wrong. if you could re run from my EDITED answer this should tell us more in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the session you would first need to start it like so:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Then $rn should become this:

```
  $rn = $_SESSION['user'];
```

and the first $sql should become this:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO nieuws_bericht (title,berichten,aangemaakt) VALUES('$fn','$ln','$rn')";
```

**Always prepare your query's**

**OPTION 1 ($MySQLiconn)**

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(1);
include_once 'dbcon.php';

if(isset($_POST['save_mul']))
{       
    $total = $_POST['total'];

    for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++)
    {
        $fn = $_POST["fname$i"];
        $ln = $_POST["lname$i"];   
        $rn = $_SESSION]['user'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO nieuws_bericht (title,berichten,aangemaakt) VALUES('$fn','$ln','$rn')";
        $sql = $MySQLiconn->query($sql)or die($MySQLiconn->error);        
    }

    if($sql)
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("<?=$total?> bericht(en) zijn aangemaakt !!!");
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while inserting , TRY AGAIN');
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

**OPTION 2 (mysql_)**

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(1);
include_once 'dbcon.php';

if(isset($_POST['save_mul']))
{       
    $total = $_POST['total'];

    for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++)
    {
        $fn = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["fname$i"]));
        $ln = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["lname$i"]));   
        $rn = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_SESSION]['user']));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO nieuws_bericht (title,berichten,aangemaakt) VALUES('$fn','$ln','$rn')";
        $sql = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());        
    }

    if($sql)
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("<?=$total;?> bericht(en) zijn aangemaakt !!!");
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while inserting , TRY AGAIN');
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/reduaqi158/domains/reduankurtaj.eu/public_html/appV2/admin/dbconnect.php on line 2

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::error() in /home/reduaqi158/domains/reduankurtaj.eu/public_html/appV2/admin/add-data.php on line 31

Comment: @ReduanKurtaj You are using OPTION 1 (mysqli_*) for the add-data.php but in your db-connect.php you're using mysql_* try using OPTION 2 then db-connect.php and add-data.php should work together.

Comment: Damn... it WORKS!!!!!! after i get your OPTION 2 i get the error **Unknown column 'berichten' in 'field list'** that must be: **bericht**

Comment: @ReduanKurtaj Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to access the session, you need to announce `session_start()` before any code is outputted (at the top of your document, ideally). Change the first few lines of your PHP file to:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(1);
include_once 'dbcon.php';
```

---

Secondly, this line is wrong:

```
$rn = $_POST [$_SESSION]'user'];
```

What are you trying to do here?

To access the session's `user` variable, simply use `$_SESSION["user"]`, like so:

```
$rn = $_SESSION['user'];
```

---

Third, take another look at this line:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO nieuws_bericht 
        (title,berichten,aangemaakt)
        VALUES('".$fn."','".$ln."','".$rn."' ");
```

You're missing a bracket in the string. Change it to:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO nieuws_bericht 
        (title,berichten,aangemaakt)
        VALUES('".$fn."','".$ln."','".$rn."')");
```

Comment: when i use `$rn = $_SESSION['user']; ` i get the fault_message `alert('error while inserting , TRY AGAIN');`

Comment: @ReduanKurtaj  this is because your first $sql is conflicting with the second the first you're running the query using normal mysql_* then the second $sql you're trying to run a query string from an already ran query. Either use mysql_query or $MySQLiconn->query($sql). **NOT** both.

Comment: i got my `session_start();` in the top of my document, i just give you guys a little bit of my whole code ;)

Answer (score 0):

To use session variables simply use

```
  $rn = $_SESSION['user'];
```

you can set this variable before for loop. No need to use it in for loop

Answer (score 0):

1) Error in this line. Not closed `')'` at the end of line.

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO nieuws_bericht (title,berichten,aangemaakt) VALUES('".$fn."','".$ln."','".$rn."' ");
```

2) Change this

```
$rn = $_POST [$_SESSION]'user'];
```

to

```
$rn = $_SESSION['user'];
```

3) No need to use `$sql=mysql_query("");` As, in next line you are executing it.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO nieuws_bericht (title,berichten,aangemaakt) VALUES('$fn','$ln','$rn')";
$sql = $MySQLiconn->query($sql);
```

**Updated Code**

```
.
.
for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++)
{
    $fn = $_POST["fname$i"];
    $ln = $_POST["lname$i"];   
    $rn = $_SESSION['user'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO nieuws_bericht (title,berichten,aangemaakt) VALUES('$fn','$ln','$rn')";
    $sql = $MySQLiconn->query($sql);          
}
.
.
```